# StatusStrip transparence more than toolstrip when both's BackColor set to transparent and the form's backColor set to color with A value

Tags: winforms, colors, transparency, alpha-transparency, backcolor

I have some `toolstrips` and `StatusStrip` and i already set

> SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);

But when i set `backColor` for the Form with `A value` for example: `Color.FromArgb(170, 96, 72, 225)` i get that **the StatusStrip is `more lighter` than a toolStrip**.
Check this image:

[image: screenshot Of StatusStrip and toolStrip]

What is the reason of this?

Can i set both toolStrips and StatusStrip to same color(transparency)?

Comment: A StatusStrip is a ToolStrip with custom Properties. The background is rendered by the ToolStrip (the StatusStrip base class). The StatusStrip set the `RenderMode = System` by default (which prevents the StatusStrip from showing a colored border), while a ToolStrip has `RenderMode = ManagerRenderMode`.  -- If you want these two to have the same colors in all cases, you should implement your own `ToolStripProfessionalRenderer` and custom `ProfessionalColorTable`. Anyway, from what I can see here, the two Controls seem to have different parents.

Comment: Not clear what is the use of a semi-transparent Color in a Form.

Comment: @Jimi Yes, i forgot to mention that toolStrip has toolStripContainer1.LeftToolStripPanel parent but its backColor is Transparent.
I want to have semi-transparent color as i don't like solid colors. I like the color to be a bit lighter.

Comment: Yes, well, unfortunately that's not how *transparency* works in WinForms. At least, set the background color of the Container of your ToolStrip to the same Color the Form has. Don't set a semi-transparent Color to the Form BackColor, it's useless anyway.